# How to work whith md-datepicker and moment?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

In my application i use $scope variables of momemt type.
I'am use `md-datepicker`  from Angular Materialjs  for change dates variables at ng-model.

`md-datepicker` work only with Date type, which I can convert from moment, but after change data by `md-datepicker` `$scope` variables change type from Moment to Date.

How to convert result `md-datepicker` Date type back to moment type? 
This is need for use it in other functions which use moment.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="momentfrom" md-open-on-focus="true" name="dateFrom" >
</md-datepicker>
```

The `momentfrom` variable after work with `md-datepicker` change type to Date, which need convert to moment.

```
app.config(['$mdDateLocaleProvider', function ($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
        var m = moment(dateString, ["DD.MM.YYYY"],true);
        return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
    };

    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
        return date ? moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY') : '';
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting for `moment` is wrong. Use this in the formatDate function:

```
return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

if you want to set the date to be null on load, then use change the return to this:

```
return date ? moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : '';
```

Refer to the [AngularJS Material docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDateLocaleProvider) for further information on `$mdDateLocaleProvider` functionalities.

Comment: $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
        var m = moment(dateString, ["DD.MM.YYYY"],true);
        return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
    };

Comment: just need  return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN); return moment type, but it return Date type